# What is the non trivial example of monosemiring?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, semigroups, semiring

I considered the definition of monosemiring as: a semiring $(R, +, .)$ is said to be a monosemiring if $x+y=xy$ $\forall~x, y\in R,$ where $(R,+)$ and $(R, .)$ are semi groups. I also know that distributive laws will be satisfied in a monosemiring but it seems that every semi group can also be considered to be monosemiring where distributive laws will be trivially satisfied. What is the example of semi group which cannot be extended to a monosemiring? Or What is the non trivial example of monosemiring? I am bit scared as many questions went unanswered. Please someone answer this. Thank you in advance

Comment: No, distributive rule isn't trivially satisfied: it translates to the identities $abc=abac$ and $abc=acbc$. Basically, monosemigroups are exactly the semigroups satisfying these identities.